# pipenv: packages do not match the hashes from the requirements file

Tags: python, python-3.7, pipenv

Pipfile

I recently installed O365 and shortuuid packages using following command, which got executed with no problems on Mac M1.

`pipenv install --keep-outdated o365 shortuuid`

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]
black = "*"

[packages]
django = "~=3.2"
djangorestframework = "~=3.12"
django-extensions = "~=3.1"
django-cors-headers = "~=3.7"
drf-yasg = "~=1.13"
drf-writable-nested = "~=0.6"
email-validator = "~=1.0"
isodate = "~=0.6.0"
coverage = "*"
flake8 = "*"
pep8-naming = "*"
pyparsing = "*"
pydot = "*"
django-money = "*"
django-storages = "~=1.7"
boto3 = "~=1.9"
requests = "~=2.22"
sentry-sdk = "~=1.4.3"
packaging = "~=21.3"
django-mathfilters = "~=0.4.0"
pdfkit = "~=0.6.1"
django-phone-field = "~=1.8.0"
nltk = "~=3.4.5"
textract = "~=1.6.3"
django-restql = "~=0.8.2"
openpyxl = "~=3.0.3"
toml = "~=0.10.0"
django-filter = "~=2.4"
pyjq = "~=2.4"
html-testrunner = "~=1.2.1"
forex-python = "~=1.6"
django-tabulate = "*"
pynacl = "~=1.4.0"
phonenumbers = "~=8.12.9"
pycountry = "~=20.7.3"
tblib = "~=1.7"
html2text = "~=2020.1.16"
memoization = "~=0.3.2"
django-ipware = "~=3.0.2"
gunicorn = "~=20.1"
whitenoise = "~=5.2"
django-debug-toolbar = "*"
celery = "~=5.1.0"
django-celery-results = "~=2.1.0"
kombu = "~=5.1.0"
redis = "~=3.5.3"
faker = "~=8.10.1"
psutil = "~=5.8.0"
django-cryptography = "~=1.0"
channels = "~=3.0.4"
channels-redis = "~=3.3.0"
uvicorn = {extras = ["standard"], version = "~=0.14.0"}
psycopg2-binary = "~=2.9.1"
django-silk = "~=4.2.0"
django-server-timing = {ref = "master", git = "https://github.com/vtemian/django-server-timing.git"}
pre-commit = "~=2.17.0"
icalendar = "~=4.0.9"
jsonschema = "==4.4.0"
shortuuid = "==1.0.9"
o365 = "==2.0.21"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"

[pipenv]
allow_prereleases = true
```

Even though package version is not updated, pipenv is giving the following error during pipeline build stage which is running on Ubuntu 18.04 OS. Pipfile.lock has expected old version and it's a sha256 hash.

```
#0 453.9 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
#0 453.9 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     pyrsistent==0.18.1 from https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/46/e2/03adc9d2f17f1a144418d9776414d2a12d692fe6dac18bd1b946bd5a0aad/pyrsistent-0.18.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (from -r /tmp/pipenv-4mqic6yg-requirements/pipenv-plxp2qsv-hashed-reqs.txt (line 129)):
#0 453.9 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected sha256 0e3e1fcc45199df76053026a51cc59ab2ea3fc7c094c6627e93b7b44cdae2c8c
#0 453.9 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected     or 1b34eedd6812bf4d33814fca1b66005805d3640ce53140ab8bbb1e2651b0d9bc
#0 453.9 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected     or 4ed6784ceac462a7d6fcb7e9b663e93b9a6fb373b7f43594f9ff68875788e01e
#0 453.9 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected     or 5d45866ececf4a5fff8742c25722da6d4c9e180daa7b405dc0a2a2790d668c26
#0 453.9 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected     or 636ce2dc235046ccd3d8c56a7ad54e99d5c1cd0ef07d9ae847306c91d11b5fec
#0 453.9 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected     or 6455fc599df93d1f60e1c5c4fe471499f08d190d57eca040c0ea182301321286
#0 453.9 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected     or 6bc66318fb7ee012071b2792024564973ecc80e9522842eb4e17743604b5e045
#0 453.9 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected     or 7bfe2388663fd18bd8ce7db2c91c7400bf3e1a9e8bd7d63bf7e77d39051b85ec
#0 453.9 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected     or 7ec335fc998faa4febe75cc5268a9eac0478b3f681602c1f27befaf2a1abe1d8
#0 453.9 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected     or 914474c9f1d93080338ace89cb2acee74f4f666fb0424896fcfb8d86058bf17c
#0 453.9 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected     or b568f35ad53a7b07ed9b1b2bae09eb15cdd671a5ba5d2c66caee40dbf91c68ca
#0 453.9 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected     or cdfd2c361b8a8e5d9499b9082b501c452ade8bbf42aef97ea04854f4a3f43b22
#0 453.9 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected     or d1b96547410f76078eaf66d282ddca2e4baae8964364abb4f4dcdde855cd123a
#0 454.0 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected     or d4d61f8b993a7255ba714df3aca52700f8125289f84f704cf80916517c46eb96
#0 454.0 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected     or d7a096646eab884bf8bed965bad63ea327e0d0c38989fc83c5ea7b8a87037bfc
#0 454.0 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected     or df46c854f490f81210870e509818b729db4488e1f30f2a1ce1698b2295a878d1
#0 454.0 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected     or e24a828f57e0c337c8d8bb9f6b12f09dfdf0273da25fda9e314f0b684b415a07
#0 454.0 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected     or e4f3149fd5eb9b285d6bfb54d2e5173f6a116fe19172686797c056672689daf6
#0 454.0 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected     or e92a52c166426efbe0d1ec1332ee9119b6d32fc1f0bbfd55d5c1088070e7fc1b
#0 454.0 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected     or f87cc2863ef33c709e237d4b5f4502a62a00fab450c9e020892e8e2ede5847f5
#0 454.0 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         Expected     or fd8da6d0124efa2f67d86fa70c851022f87c98e205f0594e1fae044e7119a5a6
#0 454.0 [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:              Got        2462a2c81ebc4358d169a868f87eb9df71a7d676009fa9180632546456c37015
```

Any help to resolve this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you add some more info about your setup? What does your `Pipfile` look like, do you have packages with pinned versions? What operation did you execute that lead to this error?

Comment: @skowalak i have added my pipfile for your reference along with OS details. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I posted an answer, please comment if it did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `pyrsistent` is a dependency of `jsonschema`, which is pinned to version `4.4.0` in your `Pipfile`. There are several possible explanations for a hash mismatch when installing from PyPI. One way to simply fix the error would be to regenerate your `Pipfile.lock`:

```
% pipenv lock
```

And then reinstall all packages specified in `Pipfile.lock`:

```
% pipenv sync
```

Comment: "There are several possible explanations for a hash mismatch when installing from PyPI." Like which?

Answer (score 0):

"There are several possible explanations for a hash mismatch when installing from PyPI"
One of them:
Something was changed in code of package and changes were published with the same tag. So old 4.4.0 hash is different from new 4.4.0 hash.

Comment: Stating what could be the reason for the error is great but that is just part of the answer. Your answer could be very helpful if you can provide steps on how to resolve this error.